# GSMCellLocation in android ending up with exception

Tags: android, android-emulator, gsm

In my app,Im using GsmCellLocation class to find the cell id and lac at a particular instance.

I simple defined the class and displayed the corresponding attributes to an activity via TextView's.

The code section I used is:

```
TextView textCID;
TextView textLAC;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

   textCID= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
   textLAC=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);

   TelephonyManager telph= (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Testing2Activity.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
   GsmCellLocation cellLocation= (GsmCellLocation)telph.getCellLocation();

   if (cellLocation != null) {

   int cid1=cellLocation.getCid();
   int lac1=cellLocation.getLac();
   Log.v("%%%%GGGGF", "Hello"); 
   String s=String.valueOf(cid1);
   String s1=String.valueOf(lac1);

   textCID.setText(s);
   textLAC.setText(s1);

   }
```

The code section is ending with a NullPointer Exception...

Guys please help...

The error log is listed as:

> 01-27 12:33:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(393): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   01-27 12:33:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(393): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{sbc.testing.prjct/sbc.testing.prjct.Testing2Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   01-27 12:33:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
>   01-27 12:33:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
>   01-27 12:33:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
>   01-27 12:33:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>   01-27 12:33:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   01-27 12:33:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   01-27 12:33:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>   01-27 12:33:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   01-27 12:33:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   01-27 12:33:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   01-27 12:33:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>   01-27 12:33:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   01-27 12:33:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(393): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   01-27 12:33:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at sbc.testing.prjct.Testing2Activity.onCreate(Testing2Activity.java:27)
>   01-27 12:33:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   01-27 12:33:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)

Comment: what is the line 27 in the code..

Comment: line 27 :   if (cellLocation != null) {

Comment: show me the full code , what you past on above not available in your question..

Comment: Try a clean, rebuild, and fresh install.  `if (cellLocation != null)` should not be throwing NPEs so I suspect something is out of sync.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem. The reason behind that is the emulator does not have any real GSM or CDMA network, so the object of GsmCellLocation might be initialized with null. However, when I tried the same on a live device with a GSM network, it worked without errors.

Comment: Hey Hitesh i have tested with live devices but its not worked.

Comment: I believe you need to have ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission to get the data. I just tried out and got the results.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you request permission

```
     if (
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
        //ask for permission
        askPermission();
    } 
     private void askPermission() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_REQUEST);
}
```

then of course you need to override the onRequest permission method

```
     @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == LOCATION_REQUEST) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // do what need to be done

            Toast.makeText(this, "We have Permission onRequest", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }


        }
    }
}
```